# JQuery Week Calendar: Only shows header on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-week-calendar

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pRqPz/7/

When I click on a button to hide one div and show another (which has the calendar), only the calendar header loads.

When I click to another view and click back, the entire calendar loads. I've tried refreshing the calendar after giving it data, but no luck.

What am I doing wrong? Not waiting for div to fully load?

Here's my week calendar init code:

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar').weekCalendar({
                          firstDayOfWeek: 1,
                          daysToShow: 5,
                          useShortDayNames: true,
                          showHeader: false,
                          timeslotsPerHour: 4,
                          scrollToHourMillis : 0,
                          height: function($calendar){
                            return $(window).height() - $('h1').outerHeight(true);
                          },
                          data: eventData
                        });
```

Thank you again for helpful tips!

Comment: Can you update the fiddle with something that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I do sell jsp stuff in jsfiddle output.can you please update it?

Comment: sorry, just trying to figure out how to get the week calendar js files into the fiddle.

Comment: I've added the week calendar .css and .js files as external resources. There is no CDN.

Comment: Don't know if it matters but I also get this error when showing the div: Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with jquery week calendar JS file. It was created for compatibility with jquery 1.4. 1.9 deprecated the $.browser member.

My fix is this:

```
// for compatibility with jQ 1.4
$.browser = {};
```